# How to see the history of the HTML spec?

Tags: html, standards, specifications

HTML Standard is a living standard, which is more or less constantly updated.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage

I want to do some research on how things have changed in the spec during time.

How do I get, let's say, what the spec/standard was on the end of the years in the period 2006-2023?

Is there a public history available like **html.spec.whatwg.org/2014 .. 2023**, so I can link to certain changes.

(Using the webarchive is not really what I'm looking for, there must be a better way.)

(Or should I resort to using `git rev-list`.)

Comment: There is the [commits](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commits) page, a link to this can be found at the top of the HTML Living Standard page, but an easier way is to use a [internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/). This goes back to 2014 but there are [alternatives](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/wayback-machine-5-alternatives-to-try/477224/), you clearly need to do some more research to find older pages.

Comment: Another thing to look at for the history of the implemented internet standard is the [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) website and the sources it uses.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WHATWG FAQ](https://whatwg.org/faq#change-at-any-time) there are frozen snapshots published as historical references.

The FAQ misses a link unfortunately, same for the main website, so the URL is a bit hidden:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/commit-snapshots/

Doesn't go back any further than 2015 unfortunately.